# sends “true” every 5 seconds. How to execute a function on the server if the request does not arrive within 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

The client sends “true” every 5 seconds. How to execute a function on the server (Node.js) if the request does not arrive within 10 seconds?  Please give an answer as an example code

Client:

```
let time = JSON.stringify({
    timeOnSite: true,
});
setInterval(() => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/time');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(time);
}, 5000);
```

Server:

```
app.post('/time', function(req, res){
  time += 5;
  console.log(time);
  res.send('ok');  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to meeting this sort of requirement is using timeouts.

Each time you receive your message, set yourself a timeout for ten seconds in the future. If a timeout already exists, clear it first.

```
let tenSecondTimeout
app.post('/time', function(req, res){

  if (tenSecondTimeout) clearTimeout(tenSecondTimeout)
  tenSecondTimeout = setTimeout (
    function() {
      /* here, do whatever you want when the timeout fires */
    }, 
    10000)

  time += 5
  console.log(time)
  res.send('ok')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Timer class` to help you. Create `instance` once and `update` on every `request`. You can pass `callback` function to execute of time escape.

**Timer:**

```
class Timer {
  constructor(time, cb) {
    this.time = time;
    this.cb = cb;
  }
  update() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeId);
    this.start();
  }
  start() {
    this.timeId = setTimeout(() => {
      this.cb();
    }, this.time);
  }
}
```

**Start to Init:**

```
const timer = new Timer(100, function print() { // Chnage time to 10000ms
    console.log(new Date());
  });
  timer.start();
```

**Update/ Reschedule:**

```
timer.update();
```

```js
class Timer {
  constructor(time, cb) {
    this.time = time;
    this.cb = cb;
  }
  update() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeId);
    this.start();
  }
  start() {
    this.timeId = setTimeout(() => {
      this.cb();
    }, this.time);
  }
}
const delay = (t) =>
  new Promise((r) => {
    setTimeout(r, t);
  });
async function main() {
  const timer = new Timer(100, function print() { // Chnage time to 10000ms
    console.log(new Date());
  });
  timer.start();
  await delay(200)
  timer.update();
  await delay(50)
  timer.update();
  await delay(50)
}
main()
```